# How print array if he created in function?

Tags: php, arrays

Arrays created in function test().

Then I would like print their on page **test.php**.

My code down:

**conf.php**

```
function test(){
$str= array(
        'items' => array(
                0 => array(
                        'title' => 'Title',
                        'category' => 'Category name',
                        ),
                1 => array(
                        'title' => 'Title',
                        'category' => 'Category name',
                        ),
        ),
        'details' => array(
                'firstname' => 'firstname',
                'lastname' => 'lastname',
        ),
        'Id' => $Id,
        'OrderId' => 'fsdfsfdsrew'
);


$json = json_encode($str);
$base64 = base64_encode($json);

$sig = signMessage($base64, $secretPhrase);
}
```

**test.php**

```
require_once("conf.php");

test();
print_r($str);
print_r($json);
print_r($base64);
print_r($sig);
```

Tell me please why code not worked?

Tell me please why weren't printed `$str`, `$json`, `$base64`, and `$sig`?

How do it?

Preferably without global parameters.

Comment: `return $str;` from your function and call as `$str = test();`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I would like print all arrays, bot one only

Comment: If you need to return all of those ( just noticed they're all created in the funciton) you need to return them as an array.

Comment: `return array('str' =>$str,'json'=>$json','base64'=>$base64,'sig'=>$sig);`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski And then how print their?

Comment: Call the same way as `$ret = test();` and print as `print_r($ret['json']);` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't without returning them as the function return value.  In PHP, variables declared in a function (the arrays you're trying to print_r in this case) are only available within the scope of that function unless you declare them global with the global keyword.

Here's the details on variable scope in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

You could construct a larger array to contain these arrays and return them from the test() function:

```
 function test(){
     //function code here....
     ////...

     $results = array('str'=> $str, 
                      'json'=> $json, 
                      'base64'=>$base64, 
                      'sig' => signMessage($base64, $secretPhrase)
                  ) ;

      return $results;
  }
```

Then call it like this:

```
  $results = test();
  print_r($results['str']);
  print_r($results['sjson']);
  print_r($results['base64']);
  print_r($results['sig']);
```

Comment: i known this, but i would like know how print their if i created `return array('str' =>$str,'json'=>$json','base64'=>$base64,'sig'=>$sig);`

Comment: big thanks for my new knowledge)

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do that: 
first, you have to return the value if you want use on other class.
on your test you can do:

```
$something = new Conf();
$someelse = $something->test();
echo $someelse;
```

Comment: in your Conf.php on the first line make class Conf { methods code }

Comment: @Guerra  you call non-static methods of classes with `->` not `.` in PHP.

Comment: @Ray you're right, sorry. Java programer thing